# Android, runtime exec removing package

Tags: android, kotlin, adb

```
val newInput = "pm uninstall --user 0 $input"
val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(newInput)
process.waitFor()
```

'input' is the package name that  want to remove. I signed the application to make it a system app. When I try to run this code I get:

> 2020-12-23 11:39:18.313 19993-19993/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening
> trace file: Permission denied (13) 2020-12-23 11:39:18.489
> 19993-19993/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file
> or directory) 2020-12-23 11:39:18.489 19993-19993/?
> E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2

How can I remove an application from another application with permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other application removal, you have to get approval from the user. You can perform this process by using intent.

```
    Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+"some.package.to.remove");
    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
    startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```